# Maximum rotation angle of a rectangle inside a given rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

I want to calculate the maximum rotation angle of a rectangle which is rotating with the center on the center of a bigger rectangle.

Here is a figure for better understanding: [fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p57ZE.jpg).

I have tried it out already but my solution is not plausible.
Thanks in advance!
Greets, Daniel

Comment: Note: The lengths and widths of both rectangles are given

Comment: Concentrate on corners of smaller rectangle and try to determine their coordinates before and after rotation. Use formula for 2-dimensional rotation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix..

Comment: My way was to split the inner rectangle into right-angled triangels using the diagonal of it. Then it looks easy to calculate normally.

Comment: Ok, other approaches may be also proper for this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both rectangle have the same center due to their symmetry. There will be four contact points on the outer rectangle if the rectangles have same aspect ratio, else only two.

Let the inner rectangle have dimensions $(2a,2b)$. The y coordinate of contact point is $B_0/2$. Radius of inner rectangle is $ \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)} $ and its x- coordinate is $ \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)- (B_0/2)^2 } $

So coordinates of contact in first quadrant are

$$  \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)- (B_0/2)^2 } ,\, B_0/2 $$

Now we can apply polar form of straight line to find $\alpha$

$$  x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha = b \tag1 $$

$$  \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)- (B_0/2)^2 }  \cos \alpha + (B_0/2)  \sin \alpha = b\tag2  $$

Let

$$ \beta= \tan ^{-1} \dfrac{(B_0/2)}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)- (B_0/2)^2 } }= \sin ^{-1} \dfrac{(B_0/2)}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2) } }  \tag3 $$

Divide by $ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} $

$$ \cos(\alpha- \beta) = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \tag4 $$

$$ \alpha -\beta = \cos^{-1}\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\tag5 $$

and finally find unknown rotation required,  $\theta = \alpha -\pi/2$

$$ \theta = \alpha - \pi/2 = \sin ^{-1} \dfrac{(B_0/2)}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2) } } -  \sin^{-1}\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\tag6 $$

Comment: Your steps are similiar to mine. The only thing, which I dont understand is the final calculation of the unknown maximum angle. "and finally find unknown rotation required, α−π/2" is confusing me. Can you apply a final formular with the needed angle please?

Comment: In general, unless the dimensions of the rectangles are chosen carefully the rotated inner rectangle will contact the outer rectangle on only two sides, not four. You would have to check the rotation angle to contact at $y=A_0$ and choose the smaller angle.

Comment: This way is also independent of the length A0. But in my opinion there is the case that the angle is limited by A0 and not only by B0 if the bigger rectangle has other aspect ratio.

Comment: I expanded a bit now. Yes,the aspect ratios much be same, else only two points ( a pair) is contacting.  Is it OK now?

Comment: I am currently checking it with Matlab, because i have results for given lengths of the rectangles. Can you tell me what side of the inner rectangle is 'a' and 'b'. Is the longer one 'a'?

Comment: $(2 a, 2 b )$ are horizontal and vertical sides As sketched by you $b>a$

Comment: This my Matlab Code with given lengths:
b = 0.68;
a = 0.914;
A0 = 0.92;
B0 = 1.31;
theta_radian = asin((B0/2)/sqrt(b^2+a^2))- ...
        asin(a/sqrt(b^2+a^2))

theta_deg = radtodeg(theta_radian)

Comment: And i get -18.2545°. The solution should be 17.2°

Comment: There are three solutions depending on relative aspect ratio$\dfrac{a/b}{A_0/B_0}$. There are three  cases in all. Two cases where two points touch and one case where four points touch.

Answer (score 0):

Find the diagonal lengt of the smaller rectangle, and find its projection onto a side of the larger rectangle.

I did a lot of misguided calculation before hitting on the answer, but you should be able to do all the calculations in three simple steps.